# SQL Best practices: Using a column to store two different kinds of data?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, foreign-keys

Suppose I have a login table containing `id`, `username`, `password`, `type`, and `linked_id`

The `type` column specifies whether that login belongs to an employee or a client.

If they are an employee, `linked_id` is their ID in the employee's table.

If they are a client, `linked_id` is their ID in the client's table.

Intuitively, this seems like a bad idea, but other than dealing with foreign key constraints, I can't think or a reason not to.

This also brings up another question: Is it ALWAYS important to have FK constraints in situations like this?

Thoughts?

Comment: I'd use multiple columns.  If looks messier (since you have a bunch of nulls), but there's better database integrity and null values take up very little disk space.

Comment: Yes, it is always good to have FK constraints in this type of linked data. Otherwise, it is easy to delete login records and leave orphaned clients or employees; or in your design case, delete employee or client records and leave orphaned login records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are thinking about your table design incorrectly. I would have the login information in one table and then point to the login record from the appropriate table. In other words, point to your login record from the employee and clients tables rather than pointing to a client or employee record from the login record. That allows you to have your foreign key constraints and removes the need for an extra field of "type"

As an example:

- Login: Id(PK), Username, Password
- Employees: Id(PK), Name, EmployeeNumber, Login_Id(FK_LoginId)
- Clients: Id(PK), Name, Address, Login_Id(FK_LoginId)

Then, you inherently know what "type" each login is by what table the data is stored in.

Comment: Excellent insight. Now that you've pointed it out, it seems painfully obvious. Thank you for the smack across the head!

Comment: Of course, now the issue is figuring out what kind of user the login represents: client or employee, which requires scanning possibly both tables (client and employee) for the answer.

Comment: Yes, but I'm assuming your username field will be indexed so even if you have to look in two tables, it will be very fast. Since you are talking about a Business to Business type of scenario, your user tables will always be relatively small.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution would be to simply add an additional column in your database and have `EmployeeId` and `ClientId` to make the table structure easier to understand.

You could also argue that you're missing an Entity in your database design.  As an example, what if an Employee was also a client? How would the current system deal in that circumstance?

You could have an intermediate table to manage this and determine the status of that Person.

I.e. have the table `Login`.

Fields: `ID, username, password, type, PersonId`

And then another table `Person` with the `EmployeeId` and `ClientId`, although I do think this would cause a lot of `NULL` values it would support the above circumstance I have described.

As an additional note, I would not want to look at the existing `Login` table, identify the linked_id field and then have to decide which table this column relates to, `Employee` or `Client`?

You could also split this out like @randyh22 has suggested and remove the `linked_id` field altogether and have the `Login` identifiers in the child tables (`Employees` and `Clients`).

Restructure:

**Login** table: LoginId,  Username, Password (Ensure it is hashed)

**Employee table**: EmployeeId, Forename, Surname, LoginId

**Client table**: ClientId, Forename, Surname, LoginId

Comment: I've worked with database designs where a column can point to any number of tables.  It's a nightmare.

Comment: @MikeChristensen - I'm currently in that situation at work.  Completely agree!

Comment: This is bad database design. Usually this situation means you are pointing the wrong direction with your IDs. In the OPs case, there is nothing so complicated that they need to have a column point at multiple tables.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In our situation, it is unethical for an employee to also be a client, so that use case won't apply here.